# how to import and use Pear XML serializer in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, xmlserializer

I am trying to use Pear XMLSerializer package ina  Laravel project.
I have included the in composer.json and did composer install and composer update.
Now how to i call it and use it in a class - what use statement I should use at top of class to use it in the class?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I spent a quite long time in order to get it work, but I couldn't, I found "StreamParser", It gave me the same functionality, https://laravel-news.com/php-7-multi-format-streaming-parser. hopefully, it will help you.